# How to set folder view in explorer for all folders via registry

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, windows-registry

I was going through a [tutorial](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-set-a-folder-view-in-explorer-for-all-folders-list-details-tiles-small-or-large-icons/) where I learned how to set the folder view of all the five  folder templates on Windows 8 - `General Items`, `Documents`, `Pictures`, `Music` and `Videos`. The tutorial is fairly easy and we have to do it step by step which is tedious. But I was wondering whether we can create a registry file which, when patched, will turn all the five folder templates to the desired view thus eliminating the manual labor.

I personally love the `TileView` and would like to turn all the five folder view templates to use the `TileView`. Can somebody shed some light on this or  provide a possible registry hack?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are the registry manipulations that I know of.
The following text is to be copied into a .reg file and be executed.
I suggest creating first a system restore point and maybe exporting the registry keys
below using regedit for safe-keeping.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;___________________________________________________
;Delete all view settings
[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags]
[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU]

;___________________________________________________
; Set default view to tiled
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}]
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000003

;___________________________________________________
; set folder type to not specific
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell]
"FolderType"="NotSpecified"
```

Other related registry keys that might need deleting may be found in this [Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813711).

Comment: The sub key `{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}` is not present on my Windows 8 machine, yet you're trying to set this value. Will it work?

Comment: This is the entry for "Generic" folders. If the above is insufficient, you could customize the view and see which additional entries need to be added to the .reg file, similarly to the method described in [this article](http://www.c-amie.co.uk/technical/vista-preserve-folder-layout/).

Comment: Can the same be done for the `FileOpenDialog` which I want to be defaulted to the `Details` view.

Comment: This should be a separate question.

Comment: One more thing, will this work on Windows 7 also?

Comment: It should - this advice came from Windows 7.

Comment: `"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000004` for Details view

Answer (score 1):

If you run "process Monitor" from "windows sysinternals" it will show you which registry entries are getting changed when you change view. You can then make a *.reg file that will import those settings. Test it beforehand as you can break things.

Comment: Does it change from system to system?

Comment: could be, since this is in the undocumented territory Microsoft is not obliged to save data in a fixed place.

Comment: If the os and patches are the same, it shouldn't change between machine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a CMD script for setting the default to, "Detailed Folder View".

```
    @echo off

    REM Delete All View Settings
    REG delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags"
    REG delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU"

    REM Set Default View To Detailed
    REG add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}"
    REG add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}" /v FileOpenDialog /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000004 /f

    PAUSE
```