# Add column in file explorer (eg script)

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, script

Is there a way to automate (eg script) the addition of a "tag" column and save it permanently for all views (all folders type) in windows-explorer in Windows 7/10. I would like to do the same on 70 computers in a workgroup and of course involve minimum efforts.
Sorry for my English.

Comment: There is some limited ability to set folder options in the registry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491999/configure-windows-explorer-folder-options-through-powershell However, that is limited to the hidden files and other settings found in Folder Options.

Comment: I would guess that the view settings are contained or set in the desktop.ini files.

Answer (score 2):

There are five file view templates in Windows Explorer: General, Documents, Music, Picture and Videos. It is possible to set the display for one or all of them to include *tags* or any other field, and to save that setting:

- Open a folder and select *Details*.
  [image: Set Details view]
- Right-click on the columns header and select *More...*.
  [image: Add columns]
- Click on *View*, *Options*, *Change folder and search options...*
  [image: Save folder options]
- Click *Apply to Folders* to make these options "permanent" for all folders using that template. Note that these settings may be lost after Windows updates or major disk cleanup.

See [Microsoft here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/812003/how-to-modify-your-folder-view-settings-or-to-customize-a-folder)  and [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/813711), or [Digital Citizen](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/configure-default-viewing-templates-windows-explorer-be-you-want-them) for more detailed explanations.

However, doing this for *each of 70 PCs* would be tiresome... **so once you have *one* PC configured correctly, use Regedit to export the keys for these [Explorer Templates](https://superuser.com/questions/793666/how-to-set-folder-view-in-explorer-for-all-folders-via-registry) and import them to the PC's.**

[You can also make all view templates the same.](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/08/18/enable-one-view-mode-for-all-folders-in-windows-explorer/)

BTW, your English is quite clear, so there's no need to apologize!